# The number of 5-vertex Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have to find numbers of 5-vertex Hamiltonian graphs to the nearest isomorphism. I found 9 of them but the answer is 8. I can't find the wrong one, maybe the answer is wrong? Those are my graphs:

[image: graphs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of Hamiltonian graph requires a Hamiltonian **cycle**, not just a Hamiltonian path.  Some of your examples, such as 4e, which is given as $*-*-*-*-*$ or any other example with a vertex of degree 1, do not count.  Some of the graphs in your list do have Hamiltonian cycles, but you're missing other cases.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, now I won't have problems with this.